# gcc enum wrong value

Tags: gcc, enums

I have a enum typedef and when I assign a wrong value (not in the enum) and print this, it shows me an enum value, not the bad value. Why?

This is the example:

```
#define attribute_packed_type(x ) __attribute__( ( packed, aligned( sizeof( x ) ) ) )

typedef enum attribute_packed_type( uint16_t ) UpdateType_t
{
    UPDATE_A = 4,
    UPDATE_B = 5,
    UPDATE_C = 37,
    UPDATE_D = 43,

     //   UPDATE_TYPE_FORCE_UINT16 = 0xFFFF,

} UpdateType_t;


UpdateType_t myValue;
uint16_t     bad = 1234;

myValue = bad;

printf( "myValue=%d\n", myValue );

return 1;
```

and the output of this example is:

```
myValue=210
```

If I enable the "UPDATE_TYPE_FORCE_UINT16" into the enum the output is:

```
myValue=1234
```

I not understand why the gcc make this. Is this a problem, a bug, or is it normal? If this normal, why?

Comment: Which version of GCC and which platform are you running it on?  (`gcc --version` tells you the GCC version.)  What is the definition of `attribute_packed_type( uint16_t )`?  GCC 4.7.1 doesn't recognize it.  And with 'packed' part commented out, GCC 4.7.1 produces 1234 as expected, with and without the `UPDATE_TYPE_FORCE_UINT16` in the enumeration.  So, you need to identify what you're up to a bit more carefully, please.

Comment: I didn't find this documented in the [GCC 5.2.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes) online manual.

Comment: gcc Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3

Comment: sorry by not include the definition for my macro attribute_packed_type(x ) __attribute__( ( packed, aligned( sizeof( x ) ) ) )

Comment: Please update the question to show that macro definition.

Answer (score 3):

You've run into a case where gcc behaves oddly when you specify both `packed` and `aligned` attributes for an enumerated type. It's probably a bug. It's at least an undocumented feature.

A simplified version of what you have is:

```
typedef enum __attribute__ (packed, aligned(2)) UpdateType_t {
    foo, bar
} UpdateType_t;
```

The values of the enumerated constants are all small enough to fit in a single byte, either signed or unsigned.

The behavior of the `packed` and `aligned` attributes on `enum` types is a bit confusing. The behavior of `packed` in particular is, as far as I can tell, not entirely documented.

My experiments with gcc 5.2.0 indicate that:

- `__attribute__(packed)` applied to an enumerated type causes it to be given the smallest size that can fit the values of all the constants. In this case, the size is 1 byte, so the range is either -128..+127 or 0..255. (This is not documented.)
- `__attribute__(aligned(N))` affects the *size* of the type. In particular, `aligned(2)` gives the enumerated type a size and alignment of 2 bytes.

The tricky part is this: if you specify *both* `packed` and `aligned(2)`, then the `aligned` specification affects the *size* of the enumerated type, but not its *range*.  Which means that even though an `enum e` is big enough to hold any value from 0 to 65535, any value exceeding 255 is truncated, leaving only the low-order 8 bits of the value.

Regardless of the `aligned` specification, the fact that you've used the `packed` attribute means that gcc will restrict the range of your enumerated type to the smallest range that can fit the values of all the constants. The `aligned` attribute can change the size, but it doesn't change the range.

In my opinion, this is a bug in gcc.  (And clang, which is largely gcc-compatible, behaves differently.)

The bottom line is that by packing the enumeration type, you've told the compiler to narrow its range. One way to avoid that is to define an additional constant with a value of `0xFFFF`, which you show in a comment.

In general, a C `enum` type is compatible with some integer type. The choice of which integer type to use is implementation-defined, as long as the chosen type can represent all the specified values.

According to the latest gcc manual:

> Normally, the type is `unsigned int` if there are no negative
>   values in the enumeration, otherwise `int`.  If `-fshort-enums` is
>   specified, then if there are negative values it is the first of
>   `signed char`, `short` and `int` that can represent all the
>   values, otherwise it is the first of `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`
>   and `unsigned int` that can represent all the values.
>
> On some targets, `-fshort-enums` is the default; this is
>   determined by the ABI.

Also quoting the gcc manual:

> The `packed` attribute specifies that a variable or structure field
>   should have the smallest possible alignment -- one byte for a
>   variable, and one bit for a field, unless you specify a larger
>   value with the `aligned` attribute.

Here's a test program, based on yours but showing some extra information:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    enum __attribute((packed, aligned(2))) e { foo, bar };
    enum e obj = 0x1234;
    printf("enum e is %s, size %zu, alignment %zu\n",
           (enum e)-1 < (enum e)0 ? "signed" : "unsigned",
           sizeof (enum e),
           _Alignof (enum e));
    printf("obj = 0x%x\n", (unsigned)obj);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces a compile-time warning:

```
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:4:18: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
     enum e obj = 0x1234;
                  ^
```

and this output:

```
enum e is unsigned, size 2, alignment 2
obj = 0x34
```

The simplest change to your program would be to add the

```
UPDATE_TYPE_FORCE_UINT16 = 0xFFFF
```

that you've commented out, forcing the type to have a range of at least 0 to 65535. But there's a more portable alternative.

Standard C doesn't provide a way to specify the representation of an `enum` type. gcc does, but as we've seen it's not well defined, and can yield surprising results. But there is an alternative that doesn't require any non-portable code or assumptions beyond the existence of `uint16_t`:

```
enum {
    UPDATE_A = 4,
    UPDATE_B = 5,
    UPDATE_C = 37,
    UPDATE_D = 43,
};
typedef uint16_t UpdateType_t;
```

The anonymous `enum` type serves only to define the constant values (which are of type `int`, not of the enumeration type).  You can declare objects of type `UpdateType_T` and they'll have the same representation as `uint16_t`, which (I think) is what you really want.

Since C enumeration constants aren't closely tied to their type anyway (for example `UPDATE_A` is of type `int`, not of the enumerated type), you might as well use the `num` declaration just to define the values of the constants, and use whatever integer type you like to declare variables.

Comment: sorry by not include the definition for my macro attribute_packed_type(x ) __attribute__( ( packed, aligned( sizeof( x ) ) ) )

Comment: I not understand why the gcc take only one byte from wrong value if the size of enum is uint16_t ?? with visual studio not happend this.

Comment: @CarlosFernandez: I don't understand it either. In my opinion it's a bug in gcc. I've updated my answer.